# Correct way of stacking animtate and animateTransform in SVG SMIL?

Tags: svg, cross-browser, svg-animate, smil

When attempting to combine an attribute animation and a transformation animation in SVG, I end up with two different end results in Chromium (78.0.3904.97) and Firefox (70.0.1), both on Linux:

Chromium:

[image: red circle enlarged and transformed]

Firefox:

[image: red circle transformed but not enlarged]

The former behaviour is what I expect, since both animations are supposed to be applied. The radius animation must be placed within the element it's applied on, and the animateTransform element inside any element.
Furthermore, Firefox applies the radius animation if the transformation animation is removed.

Why am I not getting the expected behaviour across browsers? This level of SMIL is supposed to be supported by both.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="480" height="480" viewBox="0 0 480 480" >
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
    <g>
        <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke="red" fill="none">
            <animate
                attributeName="r"
                attributeType="XML"
                values="150;200"
                begin="0s"
                dur="2s"
                fill="freeze"
                repeatCount="1"/>
        </circle>
        <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            attributeType="XML"
            type="translate"
            values="0 0;40 30"
            begin="0s"
            dur="2s"
            fill="freeze"
            repeatCount="1"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's a recently discovered [Firefox regression](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1592546)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It's a valid way to stack animations, and the Chromium rendering is the correct one.

The incomplete rendering in Firefox  is due to a regression on the v70 branch: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1592546